# Processing my form with PHP is not working

Tags: php, mysqli

on line 1 of my page i required the connection file before going on to write my code. at this point i think it is supposed to work but can not figure out why it didn't. please some one who knows better help me.

Can you help me with a sample PHP code for inserting data into mysql database using PHP, mysqli?

Thank you again in advance.

Comment: If you include the code you have, we may be able to find where your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for insert data to mysql DB using php and mysqli

```
 <?php
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "username";
 $password = "password";
 $dbname = "myDB";

 // Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }

 $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
 VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
      echo "New record created successfully";
 } else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
 }

 $conn->close();
 ?>
```